# How to retrieve the data from PostgreSQL at constant speed?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a PostgreSQL query.

```
SELECT feedback_id, name FROM feedback
```

This query runs fast (0.298 secs)

```
SELECT feedback_id, name, message FROM feedback
```

This query takes almost double the time (0.531 secs)

Here `feedback_id` is primary key and is indexed. This table has almost 17000 rows

Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: That is your exact query you are trying to optimize? You don't filter on it at all?

Comment: Yes I will be using filter for pagination,  but still there is drastic change in the performance, if I add more columns in select.

Comment: It's meaningless to compare the performance of queries that have different results. It's *doubly* meaningless to compare the performance of queries that are not the actual queries you care about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much you can do to speed up a full sequential scan.

The difference you observe is probably due to the size of `message`. If it is bigger, it will be stored out-of-line ina TOAST table.

If performance is CPU bottlenecked, you might improve speed by changing the column to `EXTERNAL` storage.

But if you want to paginate, you wouldn't use that query, nor `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, but *key set pagination*, as described in [this article](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't understand what is the key set pagination means, can you please clarify it.

Comment: I have added a link.